# My python code doesn't launch by simple double-click, but it works by running it in IDLE

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

Code is: (all of these work, but not if launched by double klick)

-asking for url, 

-launching Chrome,

-reading it, closing,

-doing bs4 stuff,

-geting data to a .txt file

It works if lauched by cmd, VS and IDLE. Unfortunately not if double klicked,
some kind of console window pops out but it hides right after and it doesn't ask for input or launch Chrome.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re
import time

adres = input(r"""WPROWADŹ PEŁEN ADRES URL PLAYLISTY Z YT np.: 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLP0.....':  """)
adres = str(adres)

przegladarka = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
przegladarka.get(adres)

dane = przegladarka.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(dane, 'lxml')

elm = przegladarka.find_element_by_tag_name('html')

nr_film = soup.find('div', {'class': 'style-scope ytd-playlist-sidebar-primary-info-renderer'})
nr_film = nr_film.find('yt-formatted-string', {'class': 'style-scope ytd-playlist-sidebar-primary-info-renderer'}).text
ile = re.findall('\d{1,}', nr_film)
ile = ile[0]
ile = int(ile)
w_dol = ile//100+1

l=1
l = int(l)
while l < w_dol:
    l=l+1
    elm.send_keys(Keys.END)
    time.sleep(4)
dane = przegladarka.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(dane, 'lxml')
przegladarka.quit()

filmy = soup.findAll('ytd-playlist-video-renderer', {'class': 'style-scope ytd-playlist-video-list-renderer'})

f = open("songs.txt", "w+")

kolej=1
for film in filmy:
    url = film.find('a', {'class': 'yt-simple-endpoint'}).get('href').replace('\n', '')
    tytul = film.find('span', {'id': 'video-title'}).text.replace('\n', '')
    link = "https://www.youtube.com"+url+"\n"
    f.write(link)
    #print(kolej, ". ")#tutaj był też print tytul ale buggi więc usuwam
    #print(link)
    kolej=kolej+1

f.close()

ile_2 = str(ile)
print("Tyle jest filmów w playliście: " + ile_2)
print(r"Teraz linki z tymi filmami są w pliku 'songs.txt'.")
##sprawdź ilosć filmów
##powtarzaj czynność: zjeżdżaj w dół aż index przy filmie będzie = ilość filmówc
##w playliście łąduje się po 100 filmów więc trzeba zrobić jakieśtam dzielenie z resztą i tyle razy wykonać
##      czynność zjeżdżania w dół
```

Well, the output should be it can be launched by double-klick on the icon.

Answer (score 0):

I've put your code in a .py file (altered it a little for to debug) and **double-clicked** on it. Then a console pop-up (as expected) and asked me for the first input. I've put in google's url and it initialized the webdriver as well (later on it failed, but that's due to the fact that i'm using google as an (incorrect) example.

So your program shoudl work (and run) by double clicking!

[image]

Here's my slightly altered code (FYI):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re
import time

adres = input(r"""WPROWADŹ PEŁEN ADRES URL PLAYLISTY Z YT np.: 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLP0.....':  """)
adres = str(adres)
print('ran this code..(before initializing the webdriver)')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(adres)
print('ran this code..(after initializing the webdriver)')
dane = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(dane, 'lxml')

elm = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')

nr_film = soup.find('div', {'class': 'style-scope ytd-playlist-sidebar-primary-info-renderer'})
nr_film = nr_film.find('yt-formatted-string', {'class': 'style-scope ytd-playlist-sidebar-primary-info-renderer'}).text
ile = re.findall('\d{1,}', nr_film)
ile = ile[0]
ile = int(ile)
w_dol = ile//100+1
print('ran this code..2')
l=1
l = int(l)
while l < w_dol:
    l=l+1
    elm.send_keys(Keys.END)
    time.sleep(4)
dane = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(dane, 'lxml')
driver.quit()

filmy = soup.findAll('ytd-playlist-video-renderer', {'class': 'style-scope ytd-playlist-video-list-renderer'})

f = open("songs.txt", "w+")
kolej=1
for film in filmy:
    url = film.find('a', {'class': 'yt-simple-endpoint'}).get('href').replace('\n', '')
    tytul = film.find('span', {'id': 'video-title'}).text.replace('\n', '')
    link = "https://www.youtube.com"+url+"\n"
    f.write(link)
    #print(kolej, ". ")#tutaj był też print tytul ale buggi więc usuwam
    #print(link)
    kolej=kolej+1

f.close()

ile_2 = str(ile)
print("Tyle jest filmów w playliście: " + ile_2)
print(r"Teraz linki z tymi filmami są w pliku 'songs.txt'.")
```

**CAUSE:**

The machine on wich you're trying to execute the .py file (by double clicking) has not been set/told correctly on what to do when this (executing by double-clicking) happens.

You want it to execute a .py file with your Python 3.x interpreter (executable).

**SOLUTION:**

Check if the machine opens a .py file by Python (see image below). If not, make it so.

In windows this can be easily done by right-clicking and then select 'open with..'. Then select Python (or browse to the location where your Python executable is installed) and check the box 'Allways use this app to open .py files'.

[image]

If that doesn't solve the problem, then make sure to check the PATH environment variable to see if you have the path to the (CORRECT) Python executable. In case you have more versions of Python (like Python 2.x and 3.x on the same machine) this can be an issue.

If that doesn't work, call it the day and unistall all Python versions and install them again (leaving all default settings during installation).